# Infinite Loop while importing Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, import

> i have this code

```
USE [DATABASE]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataExcel]

as

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select  Box, Code , Validity FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES',     'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$]')
declare @Code as bigint
declare @Box as bigint
declare @Validity as date

begin


open c 

fetch next from c into @Box,@Code,@Validity

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

Insert into Cards (Box, BarCode, ValidityDate) select Box, Code , Validity FROM     OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES',     'SELECT Box, Code , Validity FROM [sheet1$]')
fetch next from c into @Box,@Code,@Validity

end

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c


end
```

> while exporting to the table "Cards" the empty Rows are also copied to the table and the process doesn't stop , the loop goes on and on and the process is restarted over and over, the query doesn't stop from executing  unless i stop it , when i see the content of the table , i see NULL values of empty rows and the filled rows' values , and they are repeated , so how to stop the query from reading empty rows and stop it from reading the excel file over and over ?

Comment: Have you tried a `where` clause in the Excel query?  Something like `where Box <> ''`.

Comment: i tried `where box <> NULL' didn't work , i will try yours , thanks

Comment: Yes it did word with @peterm 's Method , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use something like this instead of a cursor

```
INSERT INTO (Box, BarCode, ValidityDate) 
SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
           'SELECT Box, Code, Validity FROM [sheet1$]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your loop:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

Insert into Cards (Box, BarCode, ValidityDate)
    select @Box, @Code , @Validity;

fetch next from c into @Box,@Code,@Validity

end;
```

Your original code was fetching both use a cursor and directly in the `from` statement.  This version just uses the cursor.

Answer (score -2):

I used the Task-->Import data option to transfer data from excel to sql, and was getting the infinite loop. I closed the SQL Server management studio and retried the same option and it worked for me.